# Find no. of parameters passed in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery function like this and i need to find no of parameters passed in this jQuery function.

```
function Customer(Name, Age, Location) {
    // Find no. of parameter passed in this function
    // Eg: Here parameter count = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments.length` will print the number of arguments passed to a function. This will work no matter what the function statement looks like (for example - could be `function(){}`, or even `function Customer(Name, Age, Location){}`.

Try printing to the console:

```
console.log(arguments.length);
```

or showing an alert:

```
alert("Number of arguments: " + arguments.length);
```

To print the arguments, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
{
    console.log(arguments[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

ex

```
var len = arguments.length
alert(len)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nehXB/)

Then you can access the values using the index like `arguments[0]` will give the first parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arguments.length` to find total no of arguments

And to find the arguments iterate by using following loop.

```
 function function_name() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`arguments`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments)  object's `length` method,

eg.

```
alert(arguments.length)
```